# How to get guild ID in JDA when committing onMessageReceived/onSlashCommand event

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I tried using this method:

```java
    event.getGuild().getId();
```

but I always got **null**.
(It looks like this method is simply not implemented in the Guild interface)

How can I get the id of the guild on which this or that event took place?

*P.S. I need exactly the guild id, this is necessary for storing data in json*

Comment: getId() never returns null, so I think your problem description is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the message you received is from a guild and not a private message, using `event.isFromGuild()` returns true if the message / command was sent from a guild, or you can use `event.getChannelType()` to get the channel type the message was sent in.

You can also use `onGuildMessageReceived` instead of `onMessageReceived` if you only want guild messages and not private messages, or `onPrivateMessageReceived` if you only want private messages.